Why do BF16 models have slower inference on Mac M-series chips compared to F16 models?
I read on https://github.com/huggingface/smollm/tree/main/smol_tools (mirror 1):

All models are quantized to 16-bit floating-point (F16) for efficient inference. Training was done on BF16, but in our tests, this format provides slower inference on Mac M-series chips.

Why do BF16 models have slower inference on Mac M-series chips compared to F16 models?

Your question extends the claim in the repository, the repository does not put a comparison point, while you do include a comparison point which might not be correct. Better ask the authors of that comment in a github issue.

@Dr.Snoopy Answers can correct it. It's the most likely comparison point.

No, that is an opinion, and its the basics of your question, other comparison points can be other quantization formats.

@Dr.Snoopy "All models are quantized to 16-bit floating-point (F16) for efficient inference": it'd make no sense to quantized to F16 if BF16 was faster. Hence BF16 is slower. Anyway, let me write an answer then since SO users downvotes instead of answering.

BF16 is Brain Float 16-bit, there are other ways to represent 16-bit floating point numbers.

@Dr.Snoopy BF16 has been shown to be superior to F16 some ML use cases.

Sure, but you are making assumptions on other people's claims, which is exactly what you should not do in a SO question.

@Dr.Snoopy From "All models are quantized to 16-bit floating-point (F16) for efficient inference. Training was done on BF16, but in our tests, this format provides slower inference on Mac M-series chips." one can clearly infer that BF16 inference is slower than F16. Pragmatics 101.

From https://redd.it/1glx8ul:

bf16 requires avx512 instruction set (Tacx79)

and as mentioned on knowledge.alteryx.com:

Apple Silicon (M1, M2) chips use ARM architecture, do not support AVX instructions

unlike F16, which has been around for much longer.

Apple could have equivalent instructions to AVX512, the claim that BF16 requires AVX512 is ridiculous. Nvidia GPUs support BF16 and do not have AVX512 instructions.
